# Finding emails from one file in another

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, grep

I want to find emails from one file listed as such:

```
john@blogs.com
joe@blogs.com
james@blogs.com
```

in another file listed as so:

```
john@blogs.com:+123456789
jack@blogs.com:+123456789
jeff@blogs.com:+123456789
james@blogs.com:+123456789
```

and output the lines from the second file that match with the first file also keeping in mind it needs to match the entire email from start to finish so it won't match robertjohn@blogs.com accidently.

Desired output:

```
john@blogs.com:+123456789
james@blogs.com:+123456789
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `grep`, get the newline separated patterns (strings here, `-F`) from an input file with `-f`, and match with the other file:

```
grep -Ff email.txt file.txt
```

---

With `awk`, keeping an array with emails as indexes and checking if the first field of each record in the second file is an index:

```
awk -F: 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=1; next} a[$1]' email.txt file.txt
```

---

**Example:**

```
% cat email.txt 
john@blogs.com
joe@blogs.com
james@blogs.com

% cat file.txt
john@blogs.com:+123456789
jack@blogs.com:+123456789
jeff@blogs.com:+123456789
james@blogs.com:+123456789

% grep -Ff email.txt file.txt 
john@blogs.com:+123456789
james@blogs.com:+123456789


% cat email.txt                                                  
john@blogs.com
joe@blogs.com
james@blogs.com

% cat file.txt
john@blogs.com:+123456789
jack@blogs.com:+123456789
jeff@blogs.com:+123456789
james@blogs.com:+123456789

% awk -F: 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=1; next} a[$1]' email.txt file.txt
john@blogs.com:+123456789
james@blogs.com:+123456789
```

Comment: Thanks a lot., you're the best :)

Comment: @DavidHasselhofthe2nd BEWARE: the grep command would match "robertjohn@blogs.com:..."; awk works well.

Comment: @linuxfan yea I had memory issues with the awk version, I just used grep to get the size down and then ran awk to refine it.